# Zero current detect circuit

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, zero-crossing

I would like to make a primary side regulation (PSR) flyback converter, but I have one thing I do not understand.

I read this [document](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/and90111-d.pdf) from ON Semi.

If I want to do PSR, I need to detect the diode current of the secondary.

Here are my questions

1. I do not know how to do the zero current detection (ZCD) circuit, can you give some advice or material?
2. I saw someone add a diode at the transformer to detect the zero current, but I do not understand how it works, could you explain it?

[image]

Comment: You have to be more explicit about 2.

Comment: 2) Was it two diodes? Antiparallel? In series with the transformer?

Comment: @Neil_UK in series with the transformer

Comment: @Neil_UK I add a picture

Comment: @EEC I'd forgotten that you said it was a flyback. That **can** work with unipolar current in the primary, relying on the secondary to reset the core, so diodes like you've drawn can work. It would make sense for the diode to be in parallel with a resistor, to better define the limits of 'no' current. Use a comparator to detect when the voltage across the resistor is below some threshold, so the current is also below some threshold. The diode will clamp the voltage to <1 V, so little voltage is wasted, even when using a large resistor to get small values of current threshold.

Comment: @Neil_UK Could you please draw a figure to let me understand more easily?
because I cannot imagine what you said.

Comment: @Neil_UK I do not understand why put the diode in there can detect the zero current. why I can put the diode in there, how to make sure this diode can conduct when switch turn off.